# Can points be compared in Google Closure?

Tags: range, google-closure, google-closure-library

Google Closure provides a way of finding the "deepest possible point." If I am trying to figure out if, for example, the cursor is at the end of a node, should I create the deepest possible point from the editor range and compare them for equality?

> var range = this.getRange();
>   var node = this.getRange().getContainer();
>
> var range_end = goog.editor.range.getDeepEndPoint(range, false);
>   var node_end = goog.editor.range.Point.getPointAtEndOfNode(node);
>   range_end == node_end

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_editor_range.js.html

Answer (score 0):

No. Javascript objects will always be unequal — you need to write a method to compare the two.